# Login Page is refreshing regardless of if the correct login information is entered

Tags: php, authentication

I have a login page that regardless of what the input is (correct login or not) the page just refreshes when hitting the "login" button. I've searched on stack overflow and nothing has solved my problem yet.

Login Page Session Code

```
    <?php
        session_start();

        if(isset($_SESSION['login'])) {
          header('LOCATION: test-page.php'); die();
        }
        echo isset($_SESSION['login']);
    ?>
```

Login Page Form

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
     <meta charset='utf-8'>
     <title>Login</title>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
   </head>
<body>
  <div class="form-container">
    <div class="image"></div>
      <div class="form">
          <form>
                    <h1>Login</h1>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <input class="input" type="text" id="username" autocomplete="off">
                            <label for="username">Username</label>
                            <span></span>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <input class="input" type="password" id="password" autocomplete="off">
                            <label for="password">Password</label>
                            <span></span>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <footer>
                        <button type="submit" class="gradient">Login</button>
                    </footer>
                </form>
```

Login Page Username and Password

```
          <?php
      if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $username = $_POST['username']; $password = $_POST['password'];
        if($username === 'admin' && $password === 'password'){
          $_SESSION['login'] = true; header('LOCATION: test-page.php'); die();
        } elseif ($username === 'billy' && $password === 'bob') {
          $_SESSION['login'] = true; header('LOCATION: test-page.php'); die();
        } else {
          echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Username and Password do not match.</div>";
        }

      }
    ?>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="login.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Page After Login Success

```
<?php

    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['login'])) {
        header('LOCATION: login.php'); die(); // mlac-resources-login.php
    }
?>
```

The login page is split up for readability but it is all one continuous block of code. The

Comment: You're outputting before the headers. I think that first echo will cause "headers already sent".

Comment: The block that says that the username and password don't match should be inside `else`. The way you've written it, it will always be displayed.

Comment: What does your `<form>` look like? What method is it using?

Comment: I edited the post and added the form in like @waterloomatt suggested.

Comment: Also, the else statement has been written correctly like @Barmar said.

Comment: A form's default method is `GET` and you're processing `POST`. Try setting the `method` to `post`.

Answer (score 0):

Redirects (or any kind of header for that matter) require NO OUTPUT SENT for it to work.

Outputs include:

- Echo commands
- `<!DOCTYPE html>`
- Even any whitespace could break it! (New lines or spaces)

For example:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    echo isset($_SESSION['login']); //Output
    if(isset($_SESSION['login'])) {
      header('LOCATION: test-page.php'); die(); //Won't work since there's already output...
    }
?>
```

Try changing your code to:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if(isset($_SESSION['login'])) {
      header('LOCATION: test-page.php'); die(); //This should work now!
    }
    echo isset($_SESSION['login']); //Output goes here!
?>
```

Comment: Thanks @Brixster, I'm going to try that out.

Comment: I tried this solution and I'm still having the same issue. I've edited the code in the question to reflect what you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

A form's default method is *GET* and you're processing *POST*. Either set the `method` to `post`, or use `$_GET` when processing the form.

```
<form method="post">
   ...
```

or

```
if (isset($_GET['submit'])){
    ...
```

Comment: @warerloomatt
Turns out it was adding method="post" and some js errors. Thanks

Comment: What does `it was adding method="post"` mean? What was adding it?